# CSS selector if previous element has child with different className

Tags: css, css-selectors

Having the following table, is it possible to set a particular style for `tr:first-child`, when `:first-child` of previous `tr` has a different class? On the example table I want round corners on rows 2 and 4, but not on row 5 (since row 4 first child has the same class that row 5 first child).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table { width: 100%; }
.a { background-color: red; } 
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td.a:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr><td colspan=2>title</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=a>sadsf</td><td class=a>adsfs</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=b>sadsf</td><td class=b>adsfs</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=a>sadsf</td><td class=a>adsfs</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=a>sadsf</td><td class=a>adsfs</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, surely there is no such CSS selector. What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: JavaScript to the rescue!

Comment: I want to add special formatting if previous row has a different style. I realize javascript can rescue, but this is a large application, and if there is a solution with a css selector, it will be usefull to avoid change all components of the application.

Comment: I know of now way to do this with CSS and would turn to javascript or the server-side code. It would be easy to set with CSS if you can specify different classes for the "special" rows through one of those methods.

Comment: it all depends on how much freedom you have with your css classes, you *can* accomplish this in a quasi-fashion using solely css selectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer: **No**

You can reference **[CSS Selectors here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**.

#### Long Answer:

Let's simplify your title first:

**I want to style an element, but only if that elements immediate preceding neighbor’s first child does not have the same class.**

This is easily accomplishable with javascript, but let’s pretend **you can’t use javascript** and you have a little freedom with your class declarations.

---

The first thing you should do is give each parent element a unique class name (I would choose the same as the children). So in this example it would be `<tr class=“a”>` and so forth.

Then we can style every `:first-child` with the effect you want (in this case, `border-radius`).

Later we can use css selectors to target every element, that has an adjacent sibling with the same class name (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) and we will revert or remove the style just placed on it.

Here's a fiddle using `li` elements as **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fjtratz/2/)** and below in the snippet you will see another example using `table` elements.

```css
tr {
    color: orange; 
}
tr.a > td.a:first-child,
tr.b > td.b:first-child,
tr.c > td.c:first-child {
    color: aqua; /* style all first-children*/
}
tr.a + tr.a > td.a:first-child,
tr.b + tr.b > td.b:first-child,
tr.c + tr.c > td.c:first-child {
    color: orange; /*revert the styling on select elemets*/
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="a">
        <td colspan="2">class-a</td><!--should be styled-->
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td class="b">class-b</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="b">class-b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c">
        <td class="c">class-c</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="c">class-c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td class="b">class-b</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="b">class-b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td class="b">class-b</td><!--should NOT be styled-->

        <td class="b">class-b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c">
        <td class="c">class-c</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="c">class-c</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="b">
        <td class="b">class-b</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="b">class-b</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="c">
        <td class="c">class-c</td><!--should be styled-->

        <td class="c">class-c</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="c">
        <td class="c">class-c</td><!--should NOT be styled-->

        <td class="c">class-c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok tks, I have tried moving the class declaration to the tr and it works as expected, but there is a lot of documents already written with the class on td. I was wondering if there was a solution without touching the current docs.

Comment: @fcaserio you can do it with jQuery - if you are unsure how to, a good question would be *How do I add the same class to a parent element as it's child has with jQuery (or javascript)* - [off the top of my head, here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fjtratz/3/)